# Removed field from model, migrated, but model still shows up and causes error in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.9

So this is a slightly weird thing that's happening.

I had a model with a couple of attributes, and when I removed one of them and did a migration, django removed it from the database and for some reason it doesn't appear in the automatically made migrations. But when I try to print out or output a list of model objects or even just print out one of the models I get the error `1054, "Unknown column 'items.lab_id' in 'field list'")`

Now when I go into `python manage.py shell` and type in

```
>>>from items.models import Item
>>>Items._meta.get_fields()
```

lab_id doesn't show up in the list of fields

but when I do

```
>>>from items.models import Item
>>>Items._meta.get_all_field_names()
```

lab_id does show up in the list of fields. Even though it's not in the database, it's not in my model, AND it doesn't show up in any of my past migrations. I do remember having it in there at some point, but I know I removed it. I'm just not sure how to tell django to forget about it or ignore it.

Comment: Please show your models and the full traceback.